# error 'makeHalloRichTextEditable is not defined' with Django form in Wagtail 1.10.1

Tags: django, wagtail

I'm running Wagtail 1.10.1 on Django 1.11.1 and Python 3.5.2.
I have a Django form for people to submit pages to the website without being users.

I added the next paragraph to add some more information.

The basic idea is that someone who isn't logged in can submit an entry via a form. This is the web page that shows the error message. The admin view of the information once it's been submitted shows no such errors. All the script files are appropriately loaded.

The error message on my dev machine (localhost) for the form (not the admin page) is

`Uncaught ReferenceError: makeHalloRichTextEditable is not defined
    at localhost/:136`

The relevant part of the form HTML looks like

```
<label for="id_body">Content of the item.</label>
<textarea name="body" cols="40" id="id_body" rows="10">
</textarea><script>makeHalloRichTextEditable("id_body");</script>
```

In the template that section looks like

```
{{ form.body.label_tag }}
{{ form.body }}
{{ form.body.errors }}
```

The relevant bit of the models.py file is

```
class NewsPage(Page):
    body = RichTextField(blank=True)
    submitted_by = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    submitter_email = models.EmailField()
```

Comment: The `makeHalloRichTextEditable` function should be defined in the file /static/wagtailadmin/js/hallo-bootstrap.js . Do you see a reference to that file in the HTML source? Does it show up correctly if you visit that URL directly in the browser?

Comment: I don't see a reference to that file, but it does show up correctly in the browser if I go to the URL.

Comment: Since the web page that shows the error isn't an admin page it's not surprising the admin scripts aren't loaded. I'm trying to connect a rich text field (editable as rich text in the admin) to a standard text area Django form field (looks like plain text) for non-logged-in users to submit information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Javascript code for Wagtail's rich text field is pulled in using Django's [form media](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/media/) mechanism. If you're re-using the rich text widget outside of the Wagtail admin, you'll need to ensure that the field's Javascript is output on your page, by adding a tag such as `{{ form.media.js }}` in the page header (where `form` is the template variable corresponding to your form object).